# Using Python Count Number Of Populated Cells Populated In First Column

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to learn - I have a spreadsheet that I need to open and count the populated cells (in first column) and print the count. Here is my code - I keep getting a traceback. Can you please assist?

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\am\\Book1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
count = 0

for row in sheet.col(1):
    count = count + 1
print (count)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the traceback. Nobody will be able to help you without it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `col_slice` function for this.

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\am\\Book1.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

cells = sheet.col_slice(start_rowx=0,
                        end_rowx=sheet.nrows,
                        colx=0)
count = len(cells)
```

By the way, the first column's index is 0, as usual in Python.

Comment: Many thanks that worked.. could someone also recommend good jargon free python source pls?